# Why does the to_i method result in different o/p's in different situations?

Tags: ruby

Below is the code which I tried in ruby console. Can anyone tell me why the output is different in this two cases for the same input.

```
2.1.4 :014 > def a_method
2.1.4 :015?>   puts "enter"
2.1.4 :016?>   a = gets.chomp
2.1.4 :018?>   puts a
2.1.4 :019?>   puts a.to_i
2.1.4 :020?>   end
 => :a_method
2.1.4 :021 > a_method
enter
"12"
"12"
0 (output of a.to_i)
 => nil 

2.1.4 :022 > "12".to_i
 => 12
```

Here I'm just converting a string number into integer by reading from console using gets, which is giving 0  as output. If I do the same by just giving "12".to_i then I'm getting proper output. Why is that?

Comment: do you enter `"12"` or `12` (without quotes)?

Comment: I entered with quotes

Comment: I would not expect to get a number from that

Comment: If I give with quotes or without quotes,  it goes as "12" only if am not wrong.

Comment: a string with quotes in it cannot be converted to an int by this method.

Comment: why is that? I don't really understand. Why can't i give "12" and expect 12? sorry if my question is stupid.

Comment: it is just written this way. it expects a digit as the first character.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you expect different outputs for different inputs?

Comment: When using `gets` you cannot enter anything other than a string. If `str = gets.chomp` and you enter `cat` (without quotes), `str => "cat"`, `str.size #=> 3`. If you enter `"cat"` (with quotes), `str #=> "\"cat\""`, `str.size #=> 5`. Think about it, why should `puts` be designed to require the user to put quotes around every string they enter? What a pain that would be! And if you wanted to enter a string surrounded by quotes, you'd need a pair of quotes at each end (e.g., `""cat""`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the intermediate variable `a` when entering `"12"` (with quotes)

```
a = gets.chomp 
# a => "\"12\""
a.to_i # => 0
"\"12\"".to_i # => 0
```

If you want to enter the actual number, not a string representation of it, do not use the quotes.

Comment: More generally, only put quotes around a string if the string is to contain a quote mark at each end. For example, `puts "What is your favorite rhythm?"; str = gets.chomp` and you (an English major, who knows that such names must be quoted) enter `"Three blind mice"` (with quotes), then `str #=> "\"Three blind mice\"""`.

Answer (score 1):

This output might help explain the issue:

```
2.1.1 :001 > def a_method
2.1.1 :002?>   puts "enter"
2.1.1 :003?>   a = gets.chomp
2.1.1 :004?>   puts a.class.name
2.1.1 :005?>   puts a
2.1.1 :006?>   puts a.to_i
2.1.1 :007?>   end
 => :a_method 
2.1.1 :008 > a_method
enter
"12"
String
"12"
0
 => nil 
2.1.1 :009 > a_method
enter
12
String
12
12
 => nil
```

`gets` is short for get string, so if you enter `12` it turns it into `"12"`. As Jiří Pospíšil pointed out, if you enter `"12"`, it turns it into `"\"12\""`, which `to_i` is unable to understand.